# Sitecore Multi site: the requested document was not found

Tags: sitecore

A little help here; I have this content tree with multiple sites (sorry for the poor diagram but I hope it helps):

```
Site1
  -Home
  -About
  -contact

Site2
  -Home
  -Gallery
  -Contact
```

Site 2 is working fine, but on Site 1 Home, About, and Contact Items should work as well since I can see all their preview in the content editor but on the site(localhost) it only display www.Site1.com/Home.aspx and when I browse other page under Site 1 it says:
 
The requested document was not found
The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Any idea why Site1 isn't working?

thanks!

Comment: Do the file extensions match for these other pages on site 1?

Comment: Could you post the sites section from the web.config?

Comment: the site of my web.config section goes like OptimizedQuery's post below. :) I don't know why, but changing the starting item from Site1/home to /Site1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because both sites have a `Home` item.  Also, you should review your web.config settings.  In the `<sites>` section you should have 2 entries that look like the following:

```
<site name="site1" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Home1" hostName="www.site1.com" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
<site name="site2" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Home2" hostName="www.site2.com" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

Also, make sure both domains are setup as bindings for your site in IIS.  Here is a useful document for configuring multiple sites from Sitecore SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I checked the web.config file and I found out the culprit, I set <site ... startItem="/Site1/home"> to <site ... startItem="/Site1">

Answer (score 0):

If you change your database to the Web database, can you see site 1 and it's items?

It could be that you haven't published your items, or still have your items in workflow? 
If it's a dev environment you're working on you could try working in live mode. By default there's a file called livemode.config.example in the App_Config/Include folder, if you rename that to livemode.config it'll work. Alternatively you could check it by going to the site1 definition in your web.config and set the database to web instead of master.
Both of these options will circumvent workflow and the need to publish.

If the items have been published, could you look in the logfiles and see if there's any error in there?